# Is "assert (this)" a viable pattern?

Tags: c++

Suppose the C++ below. Before calling of `a->method1()` it has an
`assert (a)` to check if `a` is sane.

The call `a->method2()` has no such assertion; instead `method2` itself
checks for a valid `this` by means of `assert (this)`.

It that viable code re. the C++ specification?

Even if it's covered by the standard, it not good style of course, and
it's error prone if the code ever changes, e.g. if the method is
refactored to a virtual method. I am just curios about what the
standard has to say, and whether g++ code words by design or just by
accident.

The code below works as expected with g++, i.e. the assertion in
`method2` triggers as intended, because just to call `method2` no
`this` pointer is needed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A (int a) : a(a) {}

    void method1 ()
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    void method2 ()
    {
        assert (this);
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

void func1 (A *a)
{
    assert (a);
    a->method1();
}

void func2 (A *a)
{
    a->method2();
}

int main ()
{
    func1 (new A (1));
    func2 (new A (2));
    func2 (nullptr);
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
Assertion failed: this, file main.cpp, line 16
```

Comment: `this` cannot be `nullptr`, (else there is already undefined behavior).

Comment: As of GCC 6, the `assert(this)` statement is removed by the compiler in -O1 or higher. See [GCC 6 Changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html). "Value range propagation now assumes that the this pointer in C++ member functions is non-null."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even if it's [permitted] by the standard

It isn't.

---

> it not good style of course

Nope.

---

> and it's error prone if the code ever changes, e.g. if the method is refactored to a virtual method.

I concede that a virtual member function is more likely to cause a "crash" here, but you already have undefined behaviour and that's not just a theoretical concern: you *can* expect things like the assertion or conditions to be elided, or other weird things to happen.

This pattern is a big no-no.

---

> I am just curios about what the standard has to say

It says:

> [`[expr.ref/2]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2) *[..]* For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall be a *prvalue* having pointer type. The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2` *[..]*
>
> [`[expr.unary.op/1]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1) The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an *lvalue* referring to the object or function to which the expression points. *[..]*

Notice that it doesn't explicitly say "the object must exist", but by saying that the expression refers to the object, it implicitly tells us that there must *be* an object. This sort of "gap" falls directly into the definition of undefined behaviour, by design.

---

> whether g++ code words by design or just by accident.

The last one.

Comment: It just requires the argument of * to be "pointer to object type", so any pointer would be valid provided it has the correct type, regardless of its content; no?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts No. The result is an lvalue referring to the object to which the expression points. If no such thing exists, what is the meaning of the expression? How is its meaning defined? How is its behaviour defined? Answer: it isn't. It has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question up front: "C++: Is "assert (this)" a viable pattern?" - *No*.

`assert(this);` is *pointless*. The C++ standard guarantees that the `this` pointer is *never* `nullptr` in valid programs.

If your program has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) then all bets are, of course, off and `this` might be `nullptr`. But an assert is not the correct fix in that case, fixing the UB is.

Comment: So why g++ doesn't even warn? And usually, GCC is very aggressive with exploiting UB to tweak generated code. But not with this particular pattern.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts First of all, the compiler is *not* obliged to warn about UB. It is *entirely* on the programmer to know all the rules and never write UB in the first place. Secondly, not all UB *can* be detected by the compiler, even if it wanted to. And, *exploiting* UB in the compiler does not amount to it *detecting* it, more like assuming it is never there and optimizing accordingly.

Comment: Chris Lattner's blog post on [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) is also very applicable to C++.

Comment: @Eljay And it, as well as other good reads, is linked at the bottom of the UB link I provided 

Answer (score 2):

`this` cannot be `nullptr`, (else there is already undefined behavior).

in your case

```
a->method2(); // with a == nullptr
```

invokes undefined behavior, so checking afterward is useless.

Better signature to mean not null pointer is reference:

```
void func3(A& a)
{
    a.method1();
}

int main ()
{
    A a1(1); // no new, so no (missing) delete :-)
    A a2(2);

    func1(&a1);
    func2(&a2);
    func2(nullptr); :/
    func3(a1);
}
```

Comment: But these objects have different lifetime, you cannot have them outside the function.

Comment: If you talk about my changes about no `new`, indeed lifetime is different, and we cannot use `a1`, `a2` after `main` ends (not lot of code to run after that btw: destructor of globals). In your code, those pointers leak, and cannot be used afterward as no variables kept those pointers (but then ownership should probably be moved to those classes).